VS Code only recognizes file when open
VS Code Screenshot
I am having issues getting VS Code to recognize my files. When home_page.dart and habit_box.dart is opened I am getting no errors or warning but as soon as I close habit_box.dart home_page.dart does not seem to recognize the file anymore.
I have tried to run the classic commands, pod install, flutter pub get etc.
I have deleted the .vscode folder
I have reinstalled VS Code

What is the question?

Could you run "flutter doctor" and edit your question to include the results using the Code Block?

flutter doctor was not showing any issues.
Question of course would be how to resolve it but I figured it out.
I was using different encodings in the files which apparently led to some errors. Changed the encoding now its working again :)

Please, post your solution as an answer to your question, so the others know it was solved.

flutter doctor was not showing any issues. Question of course would be how to resolve it but I figured it out. I was using different encodings in the files which apparently led to some errors. Changed the encoding now its working again :)
